# How to understand 'prcomp' result? '$ sdev'/'$ rotation'/'$ center'/'$ scale $ x'

Tags: r, prcomp

How to understand 'prcomp' result?
After running below code, we get prcomp result 'res.pca'.
It include '`$ sdev`'/'`$ rotation`'/'`$ center`'/'`$ scale` `$ x`',how to understand all of them. Thanks.

```
library(factoextra)
data("decathlon2")
decathlon.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]
res.pca <- prcomp(decathlon.active,scales=TRUE)
str(res.pca)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sdev` is the s.d of the principal components and also the squre roots of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix.

`rotation` is a matrix whose columns contain the eigenvectors, the principal components in the original coordinate system.

In PCA, as you set option `scales = TRUE`, it scale data `decathlon.active`, and those `center` and `scale` are the centering and scaling used to scale the data.

Finally, `x` is the matrix of rotated data, also means the principal components of your data.